# Error when re-declaring item as record via PowerShell - "The file has been modified "SHAREPOINT\system"

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

We have had a PowerShell script scheduled and executing successfully for the past 3-4 months (In both Test and Prod). The purpose of the script is to update document properties in SharePoint when certain triggers are fired from external systems. Without getting into too much detail, below is the code that has been used to update item properties for a document that has been declared a record:

```
$recordsmanagement=[Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.Records]
$recordsmanagement::UndeclareItemAsRecord($item)
$item = $list.GetItemById($item.id)     
$item.File.CheckOut()
$item[$sSpFieldName]=$sDbValue
$item.Update()                                          
$item = $list.GetItemById($item.id)                                 
$item.File.CheckIn("")                          
$recordsmanagement::DeclareItemAsRecord($item)
```

This code has worked hundreds of times without a problem. For some reason, this code started bombing a week ago on the last line (when re-declaring as a record):

```
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "DeclareItemAsRecord" with "1" argument(s): "The file /lib/folder/file.pdf has been modified by SHAREPOINT\system on 10 Oct 2012 00:00:47 -0500."
```

The other weird part is that this is only happening in Prod. The Test environment seems to execute just fine. I haven't tried a fix for production yet, but I'm pretty sure I can just get the $item object again using GetItemById (after the CheckIn). I'm a little hesitant to do this just yet as I wanted to get some other people's perspective first.

Does anyone have any input on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: also, we had to add in "$list.GetItemById($item.id)" in a few different places because of this very issue, so that is why you see that two times (if you were curious).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best bet is to get the item again after the checkin as you say.

The error message indicates exactly that. You are trying to perform an operation on a SPListItem that has been modified. So pull it again using GetItemById before you declare it as a record.

Why it only happens on some records and on some environment I am not sure. I guess Sharepoint is a bit temperamental.

Thing I would try as well:

- Check if there is any workflow doing some work on that item when you check it in
- Try to use SystemUpdate() instead of Update() if that suits your requirements

Good luck